# Buttons on a CCScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, scroll, spritebuilder

I have a **upgradeShop.ccb** file that is a layer and it has buttons on it (it's a shop to buy upgrades). I have a `CCScrollView` in my `MainScene` that I am loading my **ugpradeShop.ccb**. Everything works fine, except the buttons. When I click a button on the scrollview, a method is called that is supposed to subtract points from the player, and add the bonuses for the upgrade, and update the points label on `MainScene`. The points label is just a `CCLabelTTF` and it tells the player how many points the player has. I also have an `NSLog` in the method to make sure that it is being called.

The `NSLog` is working fine, so the method is being called when the button is tapped/clicked. The problem is that the label on `MainScene` isn't changing. To try to diagnose this, I also attempted to hide a sprite that I have on `MainScene`, when the button is clicked. It didn't work either.

This is what I have in `MainScene`. This is the method called when clicking the button.

```
-(void)buyItem {
if (points >= 10) {
    points -= 10;
    label.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2Lf", points];
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2Lf", points]);
    [self didLoadFromCCB];
    }
}
```

I should also mention that the custom class of the `CCNode` in the **ugpradesShop.ccb** layer is set to `MainScene`. [Heres a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPqt8.jpg)

[Here is the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGvuX.jpg)

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've been trying to solve this for over a week now, and reading up on the developer library but I honestly can't find what I am doing wrong.

I'm very new to obj-c so please explain in easy terms. Thank you so much.

Comment: Is "label" non-nil? Set a breakpoint and check.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I used '    if (dogeAmount == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Nil");
    }' upon view loading and it outputted Nil. So it is nil. I'm not too sure on what this means I should do

Comment: Sorry by dogeAmount I mean label. thats what the label name is

Comment: assign it, the label variable won't magically know which label it is supposed to refer to. For instance in spritebuilder give the label a variable name "label" and have it assigned to document root.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I actually do have that. The label itself is under CCNode on MainScene.ccb. I actually update the label in different situations, for example there's a button in MainScene that changes the label text and that works fine. The difference between them is that in the problem I am having now, the button isn't under the CCNode in MainScene, but under CCNode in ugpradesShop.ccb which is just a layer. Then the scrollview loads that layer. The scrollview is positioned in MainScene so that it takes up the right side of the scene, and the button should update a label on the visible side.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D thought I would clarify a little bit more there. But yeah I have it assigned. [Heres a picture](http://i.imgur.com/a5znRaI.jpg?1?9084)

Comment: set a breakpoint in didloadfromccb to confirm the label is set correctly, if not, check the log for any messages regrding the label

Comment: @LearnCocos2D alright I think I did this correctly. I set up a breakpoint at the line where the '-(void)didLoadFromCCB {' is. I ran the program and in the log the label isn't mentioned. It does tell me about a nil label, but that one was from an old design and I must have missed it when I was redoing the design. It also outputs something about MainScene. [Pic here](http://i.imgur.com/FkL9R2y.jpg?2?3428)

Comment: expand self and look for the mainscene label ivar, see first couple paragraphs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/DebugYourApp/DebugYourApp.html

Comment: @LearnCocos2D ok I just expanded self. [Pic here](http://i.imgur.com/fiY5iv4.jpg?2?9882) DogeAmount is the label name, I'm just using "label" in this post because it's easier to follow. I don't know why it says its nil, I have it on document root in SpriteBuilder with the same name.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Okay I just tried this. In DidLoadFromCCB I put '       stringText = @"Test";
label.string = [NSString stringWithString:stringText];' and upon loading the app it worked and set the labels text to test. Then, I put the same code under the buttons method. I ran the program, and the labels text remained as "Sample Text". So I assume it has something to do with the method. Not sure

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I just created a test project and tried to change the label. This should be easier to follow since there isn't any other code, just everything I did for the scrollview. I got the same outcome. Not sure whats up. [Pic here](http://imgur.com/a/77XyJ)